# AD returns Objectsid as String and SecurityIdentifier is failing interprete this

Tags: active-directory

Usually AD returns 'Objectsid' as a `byte[]`. So I type cast the value returned by AD in to `byte[]`. This procedure worked against several AD but not in one case. In this AD environment, I get following exception.

> Exception: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'. (System.InvalidCastException)

To debug this I started checking data-type of the value returned by AD, and it was `system.string` not `byte[]`. I printed this string and it was garbage. Then I passed this string to `SecurityIdentifier()` and I got exception again.

> Exception: Value was invalid. Parameter name: sddlForm (System.ArgumentException)

Code:

```
//Using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols objects
object s = objSrEc[k1].Attributes[(string)obj3.Current][0];
string x = s.GetType().FullName;

if (x.ToLower() == "system.byte[]")
{
  byte[] bSID = ((byte[])s);
  if (bSID != null)
  {
    SecurityIdentifier SID = new SecurityIdentifier(bSID, 0); 
    String ObjectSID = SID.Value;
  }
}
else if (x.ToLower() == "system.string")
{
  SecurityIdentifier SID = new SecurityIdentifier((String)s); //ssdl excception
  String ObjectSID = SID.Value;
}
```

This is the first time I am seeing AD return string data for `ObjectSID`. I have run my code against many AD servers. I am planning to check the data-type of `ObjectSID` in AD schema.

Do any one come across this behavior? Should I call the Win32 api `ConvertByteToStringSid()`?

Thanks
Ramesh

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for reviving a graveyard post, but I had the same issue a year or so ago, managed to find out why and I figured I'd at least share the reason behind this behavior.

When using the System.DirectoryServices.Protocols namespace, all attribute values should be either a) a byte array, or b) a UTF-8 string. Thing is, the developers at Microsoft figured that they should help people by returning a string when the byte array returned from the underlying LDAP API can be formatted as one, and the byte array itself when the UTF-8 conversion fails. However, this is only true for the [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.directoryattribute.item(v=vs.110).aspx) of the [DirectoryAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.directoryattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) class, and not for the iterator (which always returns the byte array) or the GetValues method.

The safest way to always get a byte array when you want the SID is, as previously mentioned by others, the GetValues method.

Answer (score 0):

I came through the same. Found this behavior normal when deal with ForeignSecurityPrincipals, however recently found this when translate attributes of built-in groups from some old Win 2K3 domains.
I don't like this as can't just ask the result attribute to tell me via GetType() what type are you and what should I do with you ( GetValues(Attribute.GetType()) ). One of the solutions was reading all attributes definition from AD schema, but this part might be a bit heavy (depends what you're looking for) although it was only a small part of overall AD processing the solution was performing.
Cheers,
*Greg*

Comment: I changed the way I was reading values from DirectoryAttribute. That helped me solve this problem.                     DirectoryAttribute s;
    byte[] byteSID = (byte[])s.GetValues(Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"))[0];
    if (byteSID != null)
    {
     SecurityIdentifier sSID = new SecurityIdentifier(byteSID, 0);
     SecurityIdentifier dmnSID = sSID.AccountDomainSid;
     String sDomainSID = dmnSID.ToString().ToLower();
    }

Comment: @user1174790, this code is a nice solution to the problem.